# Image segmentation by texture? Cannot find any source code

Tags: opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have been looking for a long time for code to do image segmentation by texture. There seems to be many papers but I cannot find any code. Has anyone come across any code to do this? Either in opencv or any other?

Comment: Why you don't want even try to implement something you read in papers? It not so hard. Try gabor filter banks and svm, for instance (less than 1000 lines of code) and works rather good.

Comment: Thanks, but its not a matter of how easy or hard, its a matter of minimizing my time on the task as I have so many other tasks to do.

Comment: @AndreySmorodov, sorry your answer here is old, I am new with texture image. Could you put any link to that by gabor filter banks and svm, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just made a repo with code https://github.com/Smorodov/gabor_segmentation

The code is rather old, so may be it will be needed to small modifications to openCV's changes.

It uses kmeans to automatically segment texturrs by clustering.
If you want to use different classifier, you can check, pointsclassifier.cpp example in standaed opencv's examples.

Sample of segmented image:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I found some source code here.

http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~mignotte/ResearchMaterial/

It seems likely that this will satisfy my need for source code for image segmentation by texture for the moment.